# How to fix nightwatch acceptance tests on Fedora 20 (server)?

Tags: fedora, acceptance-testing, nightwatch.js

Now I trying to perform Selenium + Nightwatch.js + Mocha.js acceptance tests on Fedora 20.
And it cause so many errors.
But the main problem is:

```
client.setValue("input.hidden-file", require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/file.jpg'))
```

This code is not working on Fedora(server), but on OS X, Windows 7, Fedora(desktop) it works fine.
File which I trying to set is exists and path to file specified properly.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Fedora 20 is EOL. You should give a try some more recent version, which will more probably get some attention.

Comment: Thank you @Jakuje, I'll try it.